# Is there a way to disable "look for solution online" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting rid of 'Windows is checking for a solution to this problem' dialog box](https://superuser.com/questions/36396/getting-rid-of-windows-is-checking-for-a-solution-to-this-problem-dialog-box)

Is there a way to disable "look for solution online" in Windows 7 ?

When a program crashes then you have to hit "cancel" because it is "looking for a solution online".

I find this dumb, since it has never once found a solution online for me.  So is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

- open Action Center (either from the icon in the notification area, or from Control Panel)
- expand Maintenance and under "Check for solutions to problem reports" click on Settings
- check the "Never check for solutions" option and click OK

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you can also [disable error reporting using Group Policy](http://computeradvisors.net/windows-7/disable-error-reporting-in-windows-7-using-group-policy/), available in Windows 7 Professional or higher. Follow these steps:

- open Start menu, type `gpedit.msc` into the search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

- navigate to User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Error Reporting, and in the right-hand pane double-click on "Disable Windows Error Reporting"

[image]

- change it from "Not Configured" to "Enabled", then click **Apply** and **OK**

[image]

Comment: It is also possible to do this via a GPO http://computeradvisors.net/windows-7/disable-error-reporting-in-windows-7-using-group-policy/